# ExpressJS Views folder not rendering

Tags: express, pug

Using Express and pug templates, none of the files in the views folder is being rendered properly. The views folder is specified in app.js as the view directory and pug is listed as the templating engine.

I cannot figure out what is missing.

here are the files:

index.pug:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #[em LocalLibrary], a very basic Express website developed as a tutorial example on the Mozilla Developer Network.

  h1 Dynamic content

  if error
    p Error getting dynamic content.
  else
    p The library has the following record counts:

    ul
      li #[strong Books:] !{data.book_count}
      li #[strong Copies:] !{data.book_instance_count}
      li #[strong Copies available:] !{data.book_instance_available_count} 
      li #[strong Authors:] !{data.author_count}
      li #[strong Genres:] !{data.genre_count}
```

controller:

```
var Book = require('../models/book');
var Author = require('../models/author');
var Genre = require('../models/genre');
var BookInstance = require('../models/bookinstance');

var async = require('async');

exports.index = function(req, res) {

    async.parallel({
        book_count: function(callback) {
            Book.countDocuments({}, callback); // Pass an empty object as match condition to find all documents of this collection
        },
        book_instance_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.countDocuments({}, callback);
        },
        book_instance_available_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.countDocuments({status:'Available'}, callback);
        },
        author_count: function(callback) {
            Author.countDocuments({}, callback);
        },
        genre_count: function(callback) {
            Genre.countDocuments({}, callback);
        }
    }, function(err, results) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library Home', error: err, data: results });
    });
};
```

app.js includes this setting pug as the engine and the views folder as the location of view files:

```
...

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else, viewing this, I found something that seems to work in this SO answer: [Express ignoring views directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907526/express-ignoring-views-directory)

adding `layout: false` to the controller route, displays the files in the views folder correctly.

in the controller file above, I changed

`res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library Home', error: err, data: results });`

to

```
res.render('index', { layout: false, title: 'Local Library Home', error: err, data: results });
```

Hoping I don't have to do that separately for every controller action, but happy to see it working...

subsequently, correcting my path in app.js vs fixing every separate controller:

changed this:

`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`

to this:

`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));`

and the views are rendered correctly.